# Scraping website for my name with it in the url , incorrect results

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python so please take that into consideration here..

I am trying to write a script that will get a search url for a specific website, and return a yes or a no if my name is among the search results.

So far, I believe, that the inclusion of my name in the url itself is causing my if statement to be flagged.  I've obfuscated my name bit those values alone will result no results.. however knowing the results would be zero the script till returns a Yes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

thesite = "http://www.peoplefinder.com/people-search/MT-Fname-Lname/"
response = requests.get(thesite)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
test = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('Fname Lname'))
r = requests.get('http://www.peoplefinder.com/people-search/MT-
Fname Lname')
if 'Fname Lname' in r.text:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be entirely straightforward. However, I can take you part of the way.

I looked for a name that doesn't exist in Montana, and found that Millicent Harcourt fills the bill. I did this because the results page for this site always claims to have found some matches. I needed to see what the results page would be like when it fails so that I could parse a failed page.

In this code, I load Millicent's results and look for the names offered as 'matches'.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.ussearch.com/search/people/Millicent/~/Harcourt/MT').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> links = soup.select('.memberTeaserName a')
>>> for link in links:
...     link.text.strip()
... 
'Michael Frank Harcourt'
'Michael C Harcourt'
'Maryjean  Harcourt'
'Mary L Harcourt'
'Mandy  Harcourt'
```

To us, as human beings, none are at all similar apart from the surnames. If you can't work out how to decide to your own satisfaction whether any of these names is the same as Millicent Harcourt then that would be a good subject for another SO question.

Comment: I would have upvoted you for both the reply content AND teh Name you chose, if I could :)
So I luckily the peoplefinder.com site does in face return zero results for my name.  Which is odd as most don't. I'm using this tutorial/script as a stepping stone to eventually piping the results (whether exact name or a variation of) to a CSV, then either groking that further or manually inspecting.

Comment: @Skeer: You  may not know that, although you can't upvote an answer yet, you can mark it accepted, if indeed it has helped you. You can mark only one answer to a question in this way.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the name you search for in r.text, appears anyway - It will always be returned in the title of the result page:

```
<title>Mt Fname Lname on PeopleFinder.com | Free People Search with Addresses and Phone Numbers</title>
```

Even if the person doesn't exist. You need to find something else to search for, more specific. You need to find an html element that is more unique.

Comment: What about, somehow, narrowing down the field of search to a particular class/div object in the HTML code?